# PyQt5 choose the latest OpenGL version available

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyqt5, python-moderngl

I write an application in PyQt5. I want to use the latest OpenGL version available. I want some backward compatibility as well.

Currently I have:

```
fmt = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
fmt.setVersion(3, 3)
fmt.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
```

However I want to use the latest version possible.

I need something like:

```
if supported(4, 5):
    fmt.setVersion(4, 5)

elif supported(4, 4):
    ...
```

Here is my code:

```
import struct

import ModernGL
from PyQt5 import QtOpenGL, QtWidgets


class QGLControllerWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        fmt = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
        fmt.setVersion(3, 3)
        fmt.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
        fmt.setSampleBuffers(True)
        super(QGLControllerWidget, self).__init__(fmt, None)

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.ctx = ModernGL.create_context()

        prog = self.ctx.program([
            self.ctx.vertex_shader('''
                #version 330

                in vec2 vert;

                void main() {
                    gl_Position = vec4(vert, 0.0, 1.0);
                }
            '''),
            self.ctx.fragment_shader('''
                #version 330

                out vec4 color;

                void main() {
                    color = vec4(0.30, 0.50, 1.00, 1.0);
                }
            '''),
        ])

        vbo = self.ctx.buffer(struct.pack('6f', 0.0, 0.8, -0.6, -0.8, 0.6, -0.8))
        self.vao = self.ctx.simple_vertex_array(prog, vbo, ['vert'])

    def paintGL(self):
        self.ctx.viewport = (0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        self.ctx.clear(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.vao.render()
        self.ctx.finish()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QGLControllerWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

**EDIT 1:**

How to write a function like `supported()` above?

**EDIT 2:**

I run a version query with a window asking for OpenGL3.3 support:

```
GL_VERSION -> 3.3.0 NVIDIA 382.05
GL_VENDOR  -> NVIDIA Corporation
GL_MAJOR   -> 3
GL_MINOR   -> 3
```

Comment: So what is your question? You already included an answer.

Comment: there is no such function as `supported()` I have no clue how can I use PyQt to do that. (I just edited the question to make sure others will understand it, thanks)

Comment: "code to adapt to whether GL 4.5 or 4.4 is there?" yes some features will be optional and will depend on opengl 4.1 and 4.3 mostly. I can test if `ctx.version_code >= 410` but this may only work if i explicitly ask QT to make an `OpenGL 4.1` context.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL implementations do not give you the version you ask for. They give you a version of OpenGL that is compatible with what you ask for. 4.5 core is compatible with 3.3 core, so an implementation is free to give you a 4.5 core context, even if you asked for 3.3 core.

So if your intent is to have 3.3 be a minimum, with your code taking advantage of post-3.3 features if they're available, the right way to do it is to ask for the minimum. Then ask OpenGL what the *actual* version is, and use that to turn on those optional features.

But if you don't intend to ever use post-3.3 features, then there's no reason to do anything. If your code doesn't explicitly invoke any post-3.3 OpenGL functionality, then your 3.3-based code will run no differently on a 4.5 implementation than a 3.3 one.

OpenGL versions don't signify things like bug fixes in drivers and the like. So what version you use is a matter of the API itself: the features and functionality that version provides which your code actually uses. If you wrote your code against 3.3, then ask for 3.3 and be done with it.

Comment: Asking for core 3.3 does not allow me to use subroutines. this is why i ask for 4.x context explicitly (then it works fine) but i loose my backward compatibility this case. (i get 0 pointer for subroutine related functions)

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi: If your code needs shader subroutines, then your code *needs* GL 4.0 or better. Therefore, that is what your code should ask for. You lose backwards compatibility because your code *requires* features from higher GL versions. You ask for what you need. If you truly need shader subroutines, ask for a GL version that supplies them. If you truly need greater compatibility, stop using features from versions that are higher than your compatibility targets.

Comment: The best "app" that shows what i want would be an example browser... So if you have OpenGL 4.5 you will see 100+ examples if you have only OpenGL 3.3 you will see only 50+ examples.

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi: My answer explains how to do that. You ask for a *minimum*; you then check to see what version you actually got, and you adjust your code paths according to the version you got.